# Why does the element inserted to the div box with insertAdjacentHTML not affect the length of the similar elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodelist

I have a div box with one span (class ="choice") element inside. Even after I add some more of that span element into div with insertAdjacentHTML, the length does not change.

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(.choice)).length is not increasing even there are more of that span elements with the same class.

Please help.

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(.choice)).length is not increasing even there are more of that span elements with the same class.

Please help.

Comment: I [can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/5tkz7svj/) your issue ..? Notice, that the selector is a string, and you should wrap a string literal in the quotes.

Comment: do the elements added with javascript insertadjacenthtml change the length of the similar elements? For example if I have 4 span elements in my html and add 2 more, will the length of these result in 6 when selected with document.querySelectorAll?

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 html elements which match some query selector (like a class) and then add (no matter how) another which matches the same query selector, and then re-run "Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('...')).length", its value will change to 3

Comment: The array itself isn't mutated, you've to make a new query and array to see the changes.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the reason. I will try and let you know if that solves the issue.